# XML Not Posting properly

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, authorize.net

I am trying to make a REST API for Authorize.net in Actionscript 3. I am at the point where I am testing my functions that send data to the REST API.

Here is my function that creates an XML file and sends it to Authorize.net to create a customer profile.

```
    public function createProfile(card:Card, customerType:String, description:String=null, merchantCustomerId:String=null, email:String=null):void
    {
        //Append tag.
        var sendingObj:XML = <createCustomerProfileRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd" />

        sendingObj.merchantAuthentication.name = log;
        sendingObj.merchantAuthentication.transactionKey = tK;
        if (merchantCustomerId == null && description == null && email == null)
        {
            throw new Error("At least one profile element (description, merchantCustomerID, email) must be present");
            return;
        }
        if (merchantCustomerId != null)
            sendingObj.profile.merchantCustomerId = merchantCustomerId;
        if (description != null)
            sendingObj.profile.description = description;
        if (email != null)
            sendingObj.profile.email = email;

        sendingObj.profile.paymentProfiles.customerType = customerType;
        sendingObj.profile.paymentProfiles.payment.creditCard.cardNumber = card.number;
        sendingObj.profile.paymentProfiles.payment.creditCard.expirationDate = card.expiration;

        sendingObj.validationMode = "none";

        var rq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(endpoint);
        rq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        rq.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml"));
        var urll:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        urll.data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n' + sendingObj.toXMLString();
        urll.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        trace("URLData:");
        trace(urll.data);

        urll.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleIOError);
        urll.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleCardChargeComplete);
        urll.load(rq);
    }
```

The traced XML is proper and works **exactly as generated** when pasted into their script tester on [their web page](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#customer-profiles-create-customer-profile).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<createCustomerProfileRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
  <merchantAuthentication>
    <name>===My Login===</name>
    <transactionKey>===My Key===</transactionKey>
  </merchantAuthentication>
  <profile>
    <description>autogen</description>
    <paymentProfiles>
      <customerType>individual</customerType>
      <payment>
        <creditCard>
          <cardNumber>4111111111111111</cardNumber>
          <expirationDate>12/20</expirationDate>
        </creditCard>
      </payment>
    </paymentProfiles>
  </profile>
  <validationMode>none</validationMode>
</createCustomerProfileRequest>
```

Yet my response is a json file that declares that a root element is missing. What is the problem? I see [quite a few others](https://www.google.com/search?q=authorize.net%20root%20element%20is%20missing&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS747US747&oq=authorize.net%20root%20elem&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j69i60.2768j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) with this problem but they're all solved through issues in their respetive languages.

```
{"messages":{"resultCode":"Error","message":[{"code":"E00003","text":"Root element is missing."}]}}
```

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong. You push the data you want to send to **URLLoader.data** while you need to put it into the **URLRequest.data**: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#data

Comment: @Organis nailed it.  Data you send should be attached to the URL Request,  data that is received back is what gets put in the Loader's data property.

Comment: Yep. Wow. I wasn't thinking of that. Appreciate it.